# Exchange get mailboxes with updates Powershell

Tags: active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

I’m looking for a efficient way to retrieve all Exchange 2013 mailboxes that have been changed after a given time using Powershell.
What i am trying to do is get all mailboxes with configuration changes, read all interesting details and synchronize them into another system on a regular basis (like every 5 minutes).

So far the working way i have found is this:

```
$mbx = Get-Mailbox -Resultsize Unlimited|where-object {$_.whenchanged -gt $lasttime}
```

But as this will get all mailboxes save them and only then loop through them to filter the result it takes to much resources and way to much time (>10000 mailboxes).

Has anyone a better way to do this? If it is possible with LDAP that would be great.

Thanks
best regards

Comment: You can use the `-Filter` switch.

Comment: I previously tried using the filter switch like get-mailbox -filter {whenchanged -gt $lasttime} However this did not work due to remoting issues with the variable. Now i got it working using:  $mbx = get-mailbox -DomainController $dc -filter ([scriptblock]::create("whenchanged -gt '$lastTime'"))

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with LDAP instead, Exchange uses Active Directory as its Directory service so for example if a proxy address is added to a Mailbox the Proxyaddresses attibute https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx is updated in Active Directory. The whenchanged property is just a reflection of the Active directory values so any code that used for example LDAP to query that value would return the same results. The additional thing you can do with LDAP is use WMI to subscribe to events so you can get a notification type event when an object is modified eg https://powerevents.codeplex.com/

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Hi, i already thought about using the whenChanged attribute however this attribute is updated way to often. It is not only updated when Exchange Attributes are changed but also if normal attributes (including logintime) change. Sadly there is "msExchWhenMailboxCreated" but not "msExchWhenMailboxChanged" WMI looks definitely interesting but also like it requires huge effort just to get it working. And i am afraid that this is way too much for our project.